# SVG Gradient and Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, scroll, linear-gradients

I'm trying to alter the gradient/color of an image whilst the page is scrolled. This is the closest method I've come up with but it is very buggy and I am having problems with a "scroll gap" changing in size when the window is resized.

The jsfiddle for that is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/11x3cwnr/
And it works by the y1 attribute being manipulated on scroll:

```
document.getElementById("SVGID_1_").setAttribute("y1", 93000 + progress * 94000);
```

My main question: has anyone got any other ideas on how to achieve this? I'm stuck for ideas on this one!

Basically I want the image to change from white to black as the page is scrolled.

Images to demonstrate the problem:
[Scroll line with gap](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=14142195558214[)

Any help will be massively appreciated! 
Cheers

Comment: This is your second attempt at asking this question and you have again not articulated very well what your problem is.  I still have no idea what you are after :).  I think you are going to have to either make some images , or describe what you are trying to achieve in minute detail..

Comment: Right I've added the images, hopefully that'll explain more clearly. Here's a link to the desired effect: [link](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=7142195517712)
It wouldn't let me add more than 2 links because my rep is too low !! Cheers

Comment: this doesn't answer your question but can something like `.bg1 {box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -2px #000;}` and remove bg2 altogether perhaps better illustrate what you want to do?

Comment: Cheers for the input. Could you link to a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Ah I see.  The effect depicted in your image only happens in Firefox.  In Chrome something completely different happens.

Comment: The difference in browser behaviour is probably explained by the fact you have four different gradients in your SVG with `id="SVGID_1_"`.  Which of those gradients gets chosen varies between browsers.  I would start by fixing that.  I would also suggest simplifying your demo to the bare minimum (eg. a square) to simplify debugging.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I fixed the chrome issue. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7sopq9t6/) Still struggling with the gap issue. Hmm. Cheers.